# Translation from R to Python (data.table -> pandas): how to replace with values from another column?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, data.table

I am translating R code to Python. The R code performs a transformation on a `data.table` object. The typical datasets processed by this code are ~30k rows. My initial attempt fell short, or so I thought, so for testing, I have created a small `data.table` that is easier to work with, with the assumption that once it works for that small test dataset then it should also work for a full-sized dataset.

Below is the R code used to create the test data as well as the transformation code I need to replicate in Python/pandas:

```
# create test data.table
dt <- data.table(
  prop_avg = c(runif(5), 1/3, 1/3, NA, NA, runif(5)),  # 14 values, with two 1/3 and two NAs
  prop = runif(14),  # 14 random values
  year = sample(2000:2023, 14, replace = TRUE),  # 14 random years between 2000 and 2023
  month = sample(1:12, 14, replace = TRUE),  # 14 random months
  quarter = sample(1:4, 14, replace = TRUE),  # 14 random quarters
  winner = sample(LETTERS, 14, replace = TRUE),  # 14 random winners from capital letters
  loser = sample(LETTERS, 14, replace = TRUE)  # 14 random losers from capital letters
)

# write the data to CSV
location <- '/tmp/test_in.csv'
write.csv(dt, test_data_location, row.names = FALSE)

# Notice: THIS IS THE TRANSFORMATION TO REPLICATE IN PYTHON
# where the proportion average is one-third or NA we instead use the proportion
dt[
  is.na(prop_avg)
  |prop_avg == 1/3
  ,prop_avg := prop
]

# write the result data to CSV
location <- '/tmp/test_out.csv'
write.csv(dt, location, row.names = FALSE)
```

Now I'll read the same example data into pandas, perform an equivalent transformation, and using the "R result" data I'll then compare the pandas result for equivalency.

The Python code below works as planned. It reads the input data, performs the transformation, then checks the result against the expected result:

```py
    # read the data used as input to the R code
    df = pd.read_csv('/tmp/test_in.csv')

    # Notice: THIS IS WHERE THE RE-IMPLEMENTATION FROM R IS IN DOUBT
    # transformation
    filter_nans = df['prop_avg'].isna()
    filter_thirds = np.isclose(df['prop_avg'], 1/3)
    df.loc[filter_nans | filter_thirds, 'prop_avg'] = df['prop']

    # compare against the R result data
    expected_df = pd.read_csv('/tmp/test_out.csv')

    # sort both by the same columns
    sort_cols = ['year', 'month', 'quarter', 'winner', 'loser']
    df = df.sort_values(by=sort_cols, ascending=True)
    expected_df = expected_df.sort_values(by=sort_cols, ascending=True)

    # eliminate the index
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    expected_df = expected_df.reset_index(drop=True)

    # fill NA in order to avoid NaN != NaN issues etc.
    df = df.fillna(value=0)
    expected_df = expected_df.fillna(value=0)

    # test assertion
    pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(
        left=expected_df,
        right=df,
        check_like=True,
        check_dtype=False,
    )
```

The issue I'm facing is that the Python version doesn't work as well when applied to a real, full-size dataset:

```
DataFrame.iloc[:, 7] (column name="prop_avg") values are different (18.37861 %)
```

For the record, I've also tried these other approaches with the same results:

```py
    # method 2
    df['prop_avg'] = df['prop'].where(np.isclose(df['prop_avg'], 1/3) | df['prop_avg'].isna(), df['prop_avg'])

    # method 3
    df.loc[df['prop_avg'].isna(), 'prop_avg'] = df['prop']
    df.loc[np.isclose(df['prop_avg'], 1/3), 'prop_avg'] = df['prop']
```

The full-size dataset I'm using for the validation test was written to CSV exactly like the above example showing how the toy input and result datasets were written. However, using the same input data (as was used for the R transformation) and checking the Python result against the expected output data doesn't match as expected.

I thought that this might be due to imprecise floats when checking for the one third value. I'm using `np.isclose` for the filter condition to account for this, but I also tried subtracting a third and comparing the absolute difference against a small epsilon, as well as using a plain equivalency operator, and in all three cases I get the same result. Before I run the equivalence comparison I'm replacing all NaN values in both frames to 0 so there shouldn't be an issue caused by `NaN != NaN`. Also, I'm sorting both frames on the same columns so it seems like the ordering's not the issue either.

How can I further diagnose this error to reveal where it's gone off the rails? What other data issues can I validate to make sure that unexpected data isn't causing the issue?

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong. What is the output of `df.compare(df_expected)` on your real case. Can you share your validation test (input and output)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Corralien  I can't post any real data since it's proprietary. The compare result shows values that are still 0.33333 so apparently the filter condition on the one third value is where the issue occurs, maybe I need to monkey with the np.isclose() rtol/atol settings.

Comment: were you able to solve this?  Did you try a python datatable implementation? i.e. `from datatable import dt, fread, f; df = fread("test_in.csv"); df[:, dt.update(prop_avg = dt.ifelse((np.isclose(df["prop_avg"],1/3)) | dt.isna(df["prop_avg"]),f.prop, f.prop_avg))]`

Comment: Thank you @langtang I have found a workaround on this issue for now but I now think the issue is around the filter on 1/3 values since I see many in error with that value remaining, so it seems that somehow the float values comparison is failing to detect matches, even though using np.isclose() I was unaware of the datatable package so now I will try that approach, appreciate your guidance.